# Open pdf in flash player 10

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pdf, flashplayer-10

I need to open a PDF in flash player 10. The swf will not be running in a browser and there will not be an adobe reader program on the system. I need to know if its possible to open a PDF without converting it in any way, in the flash player. I've searched google for countless hours and nothing has come up, only conversion software and code to open it in a browser.

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: Could you describe why you need it in these specific requirements ? You are asking for alot. It will have to undergo rewriting the functionality of the viewer. Are you willing to pay for commercial lib or components ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot describe why these requirements are needed. Explain what you mean by "It will have to undergo rewriting the functionality of the viewer". At this time I am not willing to pay for commercial libs or components but I don't mind if they are suggested.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to view a PDF in Flash without either converting the PDF ahead of time to a flash format, or using an external PDF reader.

It may be possible to port some opensource PDF reader to Flash, maybe using Alchemy, but this will be a long and hard project, not something you could quickly throw together.

Answer (score 0):

If this won't be running in the browser, how will it be running? As a stand-alone .swf file? Could you run this as an Adobe AIR application? AIR does support rendering of PDF content.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but no this cannot be an Adobe Air application. It has to be a pure as3 .swf file.

Answer (score 0):

There an other alternative, read PDF bytes and render it with AS3.
Few libs already exist (on http://code.google.com):

- purepdf (with org.purepdf.pdf.PdfReader)
- as3-pdfreader (with org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser)

These PDF parsers don't support all avaiable PDF format's functionalities and I think you can't handle it with the same easiness of AIR integrated PDF reader (througt flash.html.HTMLLoader).