# Show PDF inside Flash file? (Alternatives to FlashPaper)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pdf, flash-cs5, flashpaper

I'm working on an interactive CD for a summer camp.

What are my options for showing a PDF file within a Flash projector? AIR or a .NET wrapper are not options because we can't rely on any frameworks that may not be installed on the end-users' machine.

(We've used FlashPaper in the past, but it looks bad and its not supported anymore. What's about fscommand?)

**EDIT:**

Reading a link posted in Jordan's question, I saw the possibility of embedding a web browser in the flash projector. Is there a way to embed a web browser or trigger a web browser (pointing to a particular local file) in a Flash Projector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977637/open-pdf-in-flash-player-10).  The conclusion is that its very difficult if not impossible. I found many libs for as3 that would generate PDF's but not display them.

Answer (score 0):

...what? AIR is cross-platform and definitely NOT a third-party framework.

And fscommand works ONLY on windows (ActiveX).

You would be better with a third-party class (AS3.0 class) - Googled and found this:

http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

ByteArray.org being a very respected website.

Comment: Note that, as far as I know, alivepdf is used to generate PDF, not to load them.

Comment: Aurel300 - When I said third-party, I made a mistake. I need a single independent projector file. AIR requires an install, as does .NET. The point is that AIR and .NET are frameworks that require installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are other desktop flash-platforms besides the AIR. For example **mdm Zinc** or **Northcode** (both not free unfortunately) that deploys standalone exe(cutables) and provide extra functionalities.